# Detecting loading of class library

Tags: .net, assemblies, initialization

Is there a way for class library to detect when it's loaded, in order to perform some initialization?
I've tried adding Program.cs with static Main method, which didn't help. I tried setting Startup object in project properties, but only (None) is available.

I know Win32 libraries have entry points, do .NET class libraries have them?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you looking for something related to .net or windows?  .NET doesn't have the same loader concept as windows libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly in C# or VB.NET, but the CLR itself supports [Module Initializers](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx), which I think is what you're asking for.  You'd normally need to use ilasm in order to pull it off.

It looks like somebody also figured out a way to [do it in C#](http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2009/12/16/module-initializers-in-csharp/) using Mono.Cecil.  It's still pretty complicated.  You're better off using a static constructor if you know that some specific type will be referenced as soon as the assembly is loaded.  Otherwise - good luck.